# Managing collection tins and buckets

Tags: fundraising

I am relatively new to civi and have an install that we are using for a new project. We are using it to manage our support groups and volunteers initially. Starting with a small part of the tasks that we will want to use it for we are just using civicore but will use other bits as we use it for more workflows.

One of the taks we want to use it for is managing collection tins that we allocated to fundraisers. Wondering if there is some method that people are already using for  this sort of thing. Thought of an additional contact type and relationships or using CiviCase but wondering what others do?

TIA

Comment: Further to this we were also looking at the possibility of using a custom activity of collection Tin Check out and check in with a single Collection tin contact.

We could use custom field collection on the activities for tin number, condition, colour. Just wondering how others are tracking their collection tins within Civi?

Answer (score 1):

In Civi we have a Contact named Cash that we use for this. This is an Individual contact type, no need for an additional Contact Type.

We use Price Sets (Line Items) to record Designations so we just have one "Cash" donor. Even if you use Campaigns, you could still get by with just one "Cash" donor.

Comment: not sure how this would apply with price sets as we are not looking at that yet. Our focus with this is tracking the process of the collection tins coming in and out and who it is with. Conversation and documents being tracked is also important.

The contribution that we get from the collection tin is not important at this point as we are not using that part of civi yet. We have about a 100+ collection tins around the UK and the spreadsheet approach is error prone and we get a tin back that has not been shown as being sent out for example.

Comment: Ok, my answer was based on recording the contribution $.

Comment: its probably something I should be thinking of as well as part of the process.